# Custom email Regex issue

Tags: java, regex

I have two regex one is MCC and another is CAPI things which allowed in MCC should also allow with CAPI kind of requirement is there. I made changes but two test cases failed. Please Help me to get this

```
public class EmailValidationTest {
public static final String MCC_REGEX = "^(\\w+)([\\-+.\\'][\\w]+)*@(\\w[\\-\\w]*\\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,6}$";

public static final String CAPI_REGEX="^(?!.*'')[a-zA-Z_]+[_\'+A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(?<!')+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-\'+]+(?<!'))*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";


@Test
public void testValidEmailId() {
    String emailStr = "_tom.moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testValidEmailIdWithApostrophe() {
    String emailStr = "to'm.moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdStartWithApostrophe() {
    String emailStr = "'tom.moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdEndWithApostrophe() {
    String emailStr = "tom.moddy'@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithConsecutiveApostrophe() {
    String emailStr = "tom.modd''y@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdApostropheInDomain() {
    String emailStr = "tom.moddy@compan'y.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testValidEmailIdWithSymbol1() {
    String emailStr = "tom.mod-dy@company.com";
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol3() {
    String emailStr = "tom.mod$dy@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol4() {
    String emailStr = "tom.mod'.dy@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testValidEmailIdWithSymbol2() {
    String emailStr = "tom.mod+dy@company.com";
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol5() {
    String emailStr = "tom.moddy+@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol6() {
    String emailStr = "+tom.moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testValidEmailIdWithSymbol7() {
    String emailStr = "tom+moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertTrue("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol8() {
    String emailStr = "tom'+moddy@company.com";
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(MCC_REGEX));
    Assert.assertFalse("Invalid email-id",emailStr.matches(CAPI_REGEX));
}
```

}

`testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol5` and `testInvalidEmailIdWithSymbol8` this test cases failed CAPI regex failed.

Comment: Which regexp is failing in these cases? try to comment out one or the other from these test cases, then you get closer. It may happen that both are failing.

Comment: Isn't  `..Symbol5` valid (and 7 (and 2))? (I.e `+` is a valid character in email addresses.)

Comment: Again - I think your tests are wrong. The MCC_REGEX doesn't allow a `+` last in the local part. The CAPI_REGEX does and that's correct.

Comment: Also, the MCC doesn't allow top domains longer than 6 characters - wrong.

Comment: Spamming... me... Noooo ;) [Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).